# No generation of the module index "modindex" when using Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx

I have troubles creating a document directory (html) using sphinx-build.

I tried

```
sphinx-build -b html source build
```

as well as

```
make html
```

but in both cases only the html-files search.html, index.html and genindex.html are generated. The file modindex.html is missing.

In the file conf.py I set

```
html_domain_indices = True
```

so I should have a modindex.html file. What am I doing wrong? I get no error message after building the html files. I'm using Sphinx 1.1.3 and Python 2.7 on Windows XP.

Comment: Do you have "* :ref:`modindex`" in your index.rst file? Please, provide the contents of index.rst file.

Comment: Are you using autodoc, or are you adding modules to the modindex manually? If using autodoc then you must [include `'sphinx.ext.autodoc'` in the list of extensions in `conf.py`](http://sphinx-doc.org/tutorial.html#autodoc). If manual, then use the [`.. py:module: <name>` directive for each module that you want listed in the index](http://sphinx-doc.org/domains.html#directive-py:module). Check the build for errors re: roles and directives, as modindex will not build if there are errors. I had this same issue at first, but checking for errors fixed it.

Comment: I face the same problem as Karin, where the setting of autodoc followed the checkpoints from Mark. However, it is still no monindex.html generated. Did I miss any step?

Answer (score 46):

## Short version

- run `sphinx-apidoc -o . mymodule`
- uncomment and modify `conf.py`. For this example, `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('mymodule'))`
- re-run `make html`

## Long answer

I can reproduce the issue with this sample module:

```
$cat mymodule/mymodule.py
def fn1():
    '''First function'''
    pass

def fn2():
    '''Second function'''
    pass
```

Running `sphinx-quickstart` produces the following tree:

```
$tree
.
├── Makefile
├── _build
├── _static
├── _templates
├── conf.py
├── index.rst
├── mymodule
    └── mymodule.py

$cat index.rst
.. sphinx example documentation master file, created by
   sphinx-quickstart on Mon Mar 30 15:28:37 2015.
   You can adapt this file completely to your liking, but it should at least
   contain the root `toctree` directive.
```

with default `index.rst`:

```
Welcome to sphinx example's documentation!
==========================================

Contents:

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2



Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

Running `make html` at this point produces no output in `_build/html/py-modindex.html`. This is because `sphinx` needs .rst files describing every module. Fortunately it's easy to produce using `sphinx-apidoc -o . mymodule`. 
This gives two new files, of which only `mymodule.rst` is necessary to fix the modindex issue in the question.

```
$head *mod*rst
==> modules.rst <==
mymodule
========

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 4

   mymodule

==> mymodule.rst <==
mymodule module
===============

.. automodule:: mymodule
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
```

Running `make html` at this point still won't work. But uncommenting and changing the line beginning with `sys.path.insert` in `conf.py` fixes things.

Mine is: `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('mymodule'))`

PS: to avoid an additional warning, add `modules` to the `Contents:` toctree in the `index.rst` file.

Comment: Another mistake (that I did) is not specifying correctly the output folder for ```sphinx-apidoc```. In my case the documentation sources live in docs/source folder. Of course the ```apidoc``` command was run from ```docs/```. Once all above conditions were met (proper inclusion of the modules, proper output) it worked!

Comment: Mistake also highlighted here: https://samnicholls.net/2016/06/15/how-to-sphinx-readthedocs/

Answer (score 5):

> The following is what I did for my project.

**1. Install sphinx**

```
   pip install -U sphinx
```

**2. Install theme** (I've chosen sphinx_rtd_theme. Pleaser replace it with your choice)

```
   pip install sphinx sphinx_rtd_theme
```

**3. Create a doc directory under your project file**

```
   mkdir docs
```

**4. Get into that directory**

```
   cd docs
```

**5. Run sphinx-quickstart command**

```
   sphinx-quickstart
```

**6. Run the following** ( if you've enabled autodoc shpinx extension)

```
  sphinx-apidoc -o source/ ../<modules_folder>
```

where ***source*** is the source folder used by sphinx and ***modules_folder*** is the folder your project's .py files-modules are in.

**7.** You will be prompted to **reply to the questions below** (change the answers according to your needs)

```
   > Separate source and build directories (y/n) [n]: y
   The project name will occur in several places in the built documentation.
   > Project name: project_name
   > Author name(s): your_nme
   > Project release []: 1.01
   > Project language [en]: en
```

**8. It should look like the following** if successfully run:

```
   Creating file ...<***modules_folder***>/docs/source/conf.py.
   Creating file ...<***modules_folder***>/docs/source/index.rst.
   Creating file ...<***modules_folder***>/docs/Makefile.
   Creating file ...<***modules_folder***>/docs/make.bat.

   Finished: An initial directory structure has been created.
```

**9. Edit conf.py** and make sure the following lines are not commented (#):

```
   import os               # line 13
   import sys              # line 14
```

**Note:**   .. stands for one directory up from doc directory
<modules_folder> is the folder your project's .py files-modules are in

```
   sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../<modules_folder>/'))          # line 16
```

make sure the following line exists

```
   extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc']                                  # line 34
```

change the theme if you'd like

```
   html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'                                      # line 51
```

**10. Run shpinx-apidoc command**

```
   sphinx-apidoc -o . ..
```

Note:
. >> is for current directory
..>> is for one level up directory, i.e., the <modules_folder> project directory

**11. Run make html command**

```
  .\make clean
  .\make HTML

or

   make clean
   make html
```

**12. Open your newely built webpage starting with**

```
  <modules_folder>/docs/build/html/index.html
```